# Verify a string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, match

I need to accept a string that define how many ZIP code the user will use.

Examples:

- If the user wants to use all zip codes from 1000 to 1200
  Then he will enter `1000:1200`
- If he wants to use only 1000 and 1200
  Then he will enter `1000,12000`
- combining both is possible
  `1010:1015,1019,1025:1027` will return `[1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1019,1025,1026,1027]`

I need to verify that string.
I used this to verify but it didnt work

```
/(\d{4}(:|,){0,1}\d{4})/gm
```

Comment: zip codes are allways 4 digits?

Comment: Please clarify the common understanding of "ZipCode" is a U.S. postal code which is always 5 digits. Do you mean the Zip+4 the 4 part? like 69103-0123?

Comment: "Then he will enter 1000,12000" um 12000 is more than 1200

Comment: Your question is unclear... Do you need to validate only? What if I use `1200:1000`? or `1200:1000,1500`Have you thought about that? How do you plan to validate that using regex?

Comment: First of, to validate a range 1000 to 1200 you should use `1(?:[01]\d{2}|200)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a basic phrase to match either #### or ####:####

```
\d{4}(:\d{4})?
```

Then extend it to match any number of them in a comma-separated list:

```
\d{4}(:\d{4})?(,\d{4}(:\d{4})?)*
```

Finally, surround with `^` and `$` to validate the entire line.

```
^(\d{4}(:\d{4})?)(,(\d{4}(:\d{4})?))*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand these matches after the match is found. I assume the string is validated before, if not use `if (/^\d+(?:[:,]\d+)*$/.test(s)) { ... }`.

```js
let s = '1010:1015,1019,1025:1027';
const chunks = s.replace(/(\d+):(\d+)/g, (_,$1,$2) =>
    Array.from(
        new Array(Number($2)-Number($1)), 
        (x, i) => 
            i + Number($1))
    .join(",")).split(',');
console.log(chunks);
```

The `Array.from(new Array(Number($2)-Number($1)), (x, i) => i + Number($1))` part generates a range of numbers between Group 1 and Group 2 values obtained with the `/(\d+):(\d+)/g` regex.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I tried to simplify a Regex, here's a true **validator** for your specific strings.
Looks a bit long since it matches a ***range* 1000→1200**: `1(?:[01]\d{2}|200)`

```
/^1(?:[01]\d{2}|200)(?::1(?:[01]\d{2}|200)(?!:)|,1(?:[01]\d{2}|200))*$/g
```

[Regex101.com example and description](https://regex101.com/r/cJFulH/1)

**Without the range**
the Regex is simpler but it will also match any four digit number like `0000`, `9999`:

```
/^\d{4}(?::\d{4}(?!:)|,\d{4})*$/g
```

[Regex101.com example and description](https://regex101.com/r/PIZh2F/1)

**Simplest - but not to be used a validator**
The simpler solution would be

```
/^\d{4}(?:[,:]\d{4})*$/g
```

[Regex101.com example and description](https://regex101.com/r/Pxrm9X/1)
but as you can see it will match **many wrong inputs** like the invalid `1000:1005:1020` (two `:`)